# Spring JPA Hibernate - how to access many-to-many table and join-table?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to have access to related Many-to-many table, as well as to the join table.

That's how this is going to look in database:

[image]

So, let's say I would like to have access from "X" to "Y" and "Z".

**Is it ok, to simply add "Z" with `@ManyToMany`, and "Y" with `@OneToMany` annotation?**

Right now it is purely theoretical question, I'm just designing this app, and this looks kinda strange, so **I would like to know if it is common and correct way to to that.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to model your join table you can use `ManyToOne` on the join table when referring to `X` or `Z` and `OneToMany` on the side of `X` and `Z`. You would use `ManyToMany` when you don't want to model the join table.